# City Name + Service Name Order in URL and Title Tag

Tags: local-seo

Is there data to show (or a post that suggests) the optimal **order** of using both **city name** *and* **service name** in a local business web page URL and Title Tag? (I.E. Has one of the following been shown to improve ranking?) For example:

URL: www.site.com/portland-locksmith
 Title tag: Portland Locksmith

-Versus-

URL: www.site.com/locksmith-portland 
 Title tag: Locksmith Portland

Answer (score 2):

**Title** : First, your title is very short, make it longer.
 It's important for title to look naturally. It's impossible to demostrate it in two-word title, so here's my example of good title : Super juicy oranges shop in San Francisco, California. And this is example of bad tile : Oranges shop San Francisco, juicy oranges, California. Google doesn't care at all whether word in title is first or last. But people care, so always try to write titles friendly to humans.

**Web url** : Same applies here. Google doesn't care about the name of your web. There can be orange shop named Lapopador (lol :) with domain Lapopador.com and orange shop with domain orangeshop.com and Lapopador.com can rank better for "orange shop" for example because of better content.

But when you run local business, it's good to have got name of town in url, like orangestampa.com - people will remember it better than Tapopador.com :) But avoid long urls, this can negatively affect your rankings.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, however, this did not answer the specific question that was asked.